# Always use the most recent toolset available in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I have a VC++ project that some people in the team open using VS2105 and others VS2017, but the former ones need to constantly edit the project to select v140 instead of v141 in order to be able to build. Is there a way to automatically select the most recent toolset available? I.e., in such a way that the VS2015 users use the v140 toolset automatically, and the VS2017 users use the v141 also automatically.

One idea that comes to my mind would be to have two projects referring the same source-code files, each using a different toolset. But then, any change (e.g., add a new file or a new library to the project) would have to be done twice :(

Another one could be a branch which only differs in the toolset specified, and constantly rebase as the master branch evolves, but then contributing back becomes clumsy :(

Comment: When opening a v140 project in VS 17, it prompts to convert the project to v141. You need to answer "No" and it won't ask again (need to have v140 toolset installed though). Everyone on the team should be on the same toolset or else you can't benefit from new features at all and it's a wild guess if your code still works in the old toolset.

Comment: This is a use case for switching to CMake and not putting project files in your version control at all. Although it would be simpler to just have everyone use the same version of Visual Studio.

Comment: When writing your program source code let's say with the `most recent toolset` hopelessly you cannot predict what toolset will be released in the few next years.

Comment: But that's also true for most other things, from OS version to SDK version, etc. But I still prefer dependencies like `toolset >= v140` than `toolset == v140`...

Answer (score -1):

Save 2 solution files, one `*_2015.sln`, and one `*_2017.sln`.

Start out after this by figuring out the most efficient solution for manually updating only one of these whenever needed.  Then write a script to modify the one as to create the other.  Add that script to CI or build script, Git push script, or whatever.

Anytime you find yourself uttering the words, "I find myself having to constantly do x, y, z." you should think, "How can I automate this?", followed by figuring out one or more manual methods to complete the task, then choosing the easiest one to automate - especially when a task can be completed by changing text in a file...

If you have CI set up, you should be able to tie such a script to trigger on any new commit.

(sorry if this answer is too basic...)